# What is the MD5 or SHA1 checksum of the OS X 10.8.2 update?

Tags: macos, software-update

I am choosing to download and utilize the OS X 10.8.2 dmg update method, since I have multiple Macs to update. For one reason or another, the download did not finish completely through the web browser. I continued and completed the download with `wget --continue <url>` in a terminal.

I would like to be sure that the file is without corruption, but Apple doesn't seem to post checksums with the downloads. What are the MD5 or SHA1 checksums of both the 10.8.2 delta and combo update dmg files?

Comment: While not strictly related, it seems the problem is not limited to OS X 10.8: Apple used to post SHA1 sums on 10.7.x combo update download pages (e.g. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1524), but they don't seem to do that any longer: There is no checksum on the most recent 10.7.5 combo update download page at http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1582 nor at the 'incremental' update download page at http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1583. The SHA1 check might be built in now, but that doesn't help when downloading the file manually :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to download them for work (the joy's of sustained 3MB/sec downloads, yes B not b) so thought I'd hash them for you:

[10.8.2 Combo Update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1581) 10.8.x to 10.8.2

```
SHA1: b08f10233d362e39f20b69f91d1d73f5e7b68a2c
MD5: 0b98f4a431be0a3df73ab8bcbc3a5dfe
```

[10.8.2 Delta Update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1580) 10.8.1 to 10.8.2

```
SHA1: d6779e1cc748b78af0207499383b1859ffbebe33
MD5: 19e08e0a558c59d5508fced80769c782
```

Answer (score 3):

They never post hashes because they make silent update of their combo updates!!!

the 10.8.2 has been modified between the first release date and december : they included the 10.8.2 Supplemental Update, and of course did not notify about it on their websites...
Build number has also been updated.

Thank you Apple to make updates even more transparent compared to Microsoft!

Comment: That is good information about Apple refreshing the combo update with the supplemental update. Thanks for that.

However, if you'll accept some constructive criticism, this may have been more appropriate as a comment to the original question.